# ¿Como crear un Acceso Directo a una direccion FTP con un archivo bat (o codigo VB.NET)?

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, ftp, powershell

Lo que quiero hacer es un acceso directo a un sito FTP, para que los usuarios ejecuten el .Bat y automaticamente se cree el Acceso Directo en sus escritorios y puedan abrir el sitio FTP con el Explorador de Windows.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Edit: También me puede servir un código en VB.NET

Comment: Saludos Rchrd, por curiosidad ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: esto [link](https://www.pastiebin.com/5a7500bd14262)

Comment: en ese caso, edita tu pregunta y agrega el código :)

Comment: prefiero que alguien sugiera un codigo nuevo mas entendible

Comment: buena suerte :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$WsShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WsShell.CreateShortcut("$HOME\Desktop\FTP.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "ftp://usuario:password@servidor"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

- Usando el objecto **WScript.Shell** podemos crear el acceso directo.
- Se utilizó la variable **$HOME** que indica el perfil del usuario al momento de ejecutar el script (por ello se agregó la carpeta *Desktop* para que guarde el acceso allí).
- Simplemente utilizando la siguiente estructura se puede definir la conexión al servidor ftp:

> **ftp://'usuario':'password'@'servidor'**

Comment: excelente funcionó a la perfección y de manera muy sencilla, llegue a pensar que no se podía hacer eso o por lo menos que no era tan fácil. una ultima petición solo para ponerle la cereza al pastel, es posible poner un icono personalizado de la lista de iconos de sistema de windows?, obviamente esto ultimo no es importante, solo quiero saber si se puede. gracias